Issue while building opencv with cuda support from source
I am facing this issue while building from source:
/home/akshatdogra/anaconda3/lib/libgsttag-1.0.so.0: undefined reference to `gst_make_element_message_details'
/home/akshatdogra/anaconda3/lib/libgsttag-1.0.so.0: undefined reference to `gst_element_message_full_with_details'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_perf_videoio.dir/build.make:161: recipe for target 'bin/opencv_perf_videoio' failed
make[2]: *** [bin/opencv_perf_videoio] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/akshatdogra/installed_packages/opencv/build'
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:6434: recipe for target 'modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_perf_videoio.dir/all' failed

This might be an issue with anaconda3 so I tried updating it but the issue still persists. I am using conda 24.3.0.
This is how I built opencv:
cmake 
\-D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE 
\-D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/akshatdogra/installed_packages/opencv1 
\-D WITH_CUDA=ON 
\-D WITH_CUDNN=ON 
\-D WITH_CUBLAS=ON 
\-D WITH_TBB=ON 
\-D OPENCV_DNN_CUDA=ON 
\-D OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON 
\-D CUDA_ARCH_BIN=7.5 
\-D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/home/akshatdogra/installed_packages/opencv_contrib/ 
\-D BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF 
\-D HAVE_opencv_python3=ON   -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/home/akshatdogra/installed_packages/opencv_contrib/modules ..

I am on a server and don't have sudo access.

Does this answer your question? Cgo "undefined reference" (gstreamer)
